# Reverse Geocoding in uwp and c#

Tags: uwp, reverse-geocoding

Ok so I am reading the Microsoft Docs for reverse geocoding

So I am trying to get my city and country code, I am following this

```
 // The location to reverse geocode.
   BasicGeoposition location = new BasicGeoposition();
   location.Latitude = 47.643;
   location.Longitude = -122.131;
   Geopoint pointToReverseGeocode = new Geopoint(location);

   // Reverse geocode the specified geographic location.
   MapLocationFinderResult result =
         await MapLocationFinder.FindLocationsAtAsync(pointToReverseGeocode);

   // If the query returns results, display the name of the town
   // contained in the address of the first result.
   if (result.Status == MapLocationFinderStatus.Success)
   {
      tbOutputText.Text = "town = " +
            result.Locations[0].Address.Town;
```

I am trying to de this in my app, I know that Address, have those 2 properties that I need (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Services.Maps.MapAddress)
Currently my app gets my position, and my coordinates, but how can I get reverse geocode working.

```
public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();

          var pos = GetCityData();
        }

        private async Task<string> GetCityData() {
            var citydata = await LocationManager.GetGeopositionAsync();

            BasicGeoposition geoposition = new BasicGeoposition() {
                Latitude = citydata.Coordinate.Point.Position.Latitude, Longitude = citydata.Coordinate.Point.Position.Longitude
            };
            Geopoint geopoint = new Geopoint(geoposition);

            MapLocationFinderResult finderResult = await MapLocationFinder.FindLocationsAtAsync(geopoint);

            return $"{finderResult.Locations[0].Address.Town},{finderResult.Locations[0].Address.CountryCode}";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check `finderResult.Status`, maybe it is `InvalidCredentials`. If you can't get the result of reverse geocoding, it is probably because you didn't add the **Token** of Map service.

Go to [here](https://www.bingmapsportal.com) and create a key. Then add it to your app:

```cs
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    MapService.ServiceToken = "your_token";
}
```

This is the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/maps-and-location/authentication-key) about request authentication key.

Best regards.

Comment: I am still getting invalid Credentials, I don't have anything on the xaml, I just want to reversegeocoding my position

Comment: You don't need to create a MapControl in XAML, but since UWP's `MapLocationFinder.FindLocationsAtAsync` uses the Bing Maps service, you need to register a token first, which is the basis for your use of related services. You can only work after the `MapService.ServiceToken` is set.

Comment: still getting invalid, I switch to the Rest Json version, that works

Comment: Thank you is working now, maybe Microsoft had to wait, before activating my key?